How to use `unproject(_:from:to:ontoPlane:)` of Content of RealityView using Apple's RealityKit
When using ARView of RealityKit, I can code like this
let results = arView.raycast(from: point, allowing: .estimatedPlane, alignment: .any)

to get the 3D position of where I tap on the plane. In iOS 18, we can use RealityView and I found that unproject(_:from:to:ontoPlane:) may implement the same function, but I don't know how to set the ontoPlane parameter.
Can someone help me with some code snippets?
